# themoviedb api Search Movie

Tags: reactjs, api, video, undefined, themoviedb-api

I'm stuck. I am using movie api for search movie. I have done the api part. But when I type a random nonsense word in the search section, my application gives an error because there is no such movie. How can I get past this? I am sharing my codes below.

Thats movie area;

```
 <div>
      <h4>{movie[0].title}</h4>
      <img
        src={`${base_URL}${movie[0].poster_path}`}
        alt={movie[0].title}
      />
    </div>
```

Thats search from

```
<label>
      <span>Search Film:</span>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={search}
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
      />
    </label>
```

Thats States

```
 const [movie, setMovie] = useState([{ title: "The Matrix Resurrections" }]); 

 const [search, setSearch] = useState("The Matrix Resurrections");
```

[movie1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bofqN.jpg)

[movie2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjmik.jpg)

[myError when i type "sadsafasfas" search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAdyJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the response you got from searching "nonsense" value using themoviedb api returning an empty object. To get through this, you can use a conditional component that checks the value of `movie[0]`. Your code can be written like this

```
<div>
{
   movie[0] ?
     <>
      <h4>{movie[0].title}</h4>
      <img
        src={`${base_URL}${movie[0].poster_path}`}
        alt={movie[0].title}
      /> 
     </>
       :
     <>
      <h4>Sorry, movie not found</h4> //your component if nothing returned from api
     </>
 }   
</div>
```